# How to add traffic ID's to multiple different links?

Tags: javascript

I'm not a coder, but I know this should not be too hard.

Currently I'm running this script on my site to track where the traffic is coming from when they purchase through the affiliate links on my website:

```
 <script>
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return("");
}

window.onload = function(){
    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="https://example.com/c/215029/222"]');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
    element.href = "https://example.com/c/215029/222/?tid=" + getQueryVariable("tid");
});
}
</script>
```

When someone visits my site with this url `https://mywebsite.com/tid=facebook` the above script is changing the specific link on my website to `https://example.com/c/215029/222/?tid=facebook`

My question is how to change the code so that it can change multiple links on my website to accept `/?tid=facebook` when I add `/?tid=facebook` at the end of the visitors url?

Let's say I also have a second link on my website `https://example.com/c/215029/example2` that needs to adapt the `/?tid=facebook` so that it becomes `https://example.com/c/215029/example2/?tid=facebook`

What needs to be changed in the code above to make this work?

I hope I explained correctly

Comment: Tip: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams instead of string-splitting like that (to account for encoding and other vagarities of data parsing).

Comment: I understand your method is a better solution. Unfortunately this goes above my head as I'm no coder :). The above script has always worked great but I have no idea how to add the extra URL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the logic of the following example:

```js
function setUrlQuery(link, params)
{
  console.log("[setUrlQuery]: INPUT URL # ", link);
  const url = new URL(String(link));
  const se = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(params)) {
    se.set(key, val);
  }
  url.search = se.toString();
  return url.toString();
}

function delUrlQueryParam(link, ...par)
{
   console.log("[delUrlQueryParam]: INPUT URL # ", link);
   const url = new URL(String(link))
   const se = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
   if (par.length > 0) {
      par.forEach((val) => se.delete(String(val)));
   }
   url.search = se.toString();
   return url.toString();
  }

// set new parametres if not exists
const result = setUrlQuery("https://example.com/c/215029/example2/", {
  foo: "123",
  baz: "false"
});
console.log("[setUrlQuery]: RESULT # ", result);

// Update an existing values in the url query string.
const result_2 = setUrlQuery(result, {
  tid: "facebook",
  foo: "0",
  baz: "true"
});
console.log("[setUrlQuery]: RESULT # ", result_2);

// Delete an existing values
const result_3 = delUrlQueryParam(result_2, "foo", "baz");
console.log("[delUrlQueryParam]: RESULT # ", result_3);
```